# Bind-mounting location on Docker registry results in timeouts

Tags: macos, mount, docker, timeout

I’m using Docker on Mac, and I’m having some trouble with bind-mounting a location on a registry server- I was hoping someone here might be able to help.

Thankfully, the issue is pretty simple. Let’s say I want to run a simple, insecure, docker registry. First, I make sure that the appropriate ip:portno is entered into the "insecure registries" list. As per the documentation, I then run `docker run -d --restart=always --name registry -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 -p 5000:5000 registry:2`

When I do that, the registry "just works." I can tag an image as `10.0.3.59:5000/imgname`, and push and pull normally.

However, I'd like the registry's data to be located at a specific location on the host system, say, `/mnt/registry`. I go to the docker preferences, make sure that sharing is enabled on the `mnt` folder, and remove old images and containers

Following the documentation again, I run `docker run -d --restart=always --name registry -v storage:/var/lib/registry/ -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 -p 5000:5000 registry:2`. However, if I now try to do a `docker push 10.0.3.59:5000/imgname` now, I get the following messages

```
The push refers to a repository [10.0.3.52:5000/cropspokyimage]
74146a4cf164: Retrying in 9 seconds
6c45ce1e774e: Retrying in 9 seconds 
0914c5636fb4: Retrying in 9 seconds
f859b8ada191: Retrying in 9 seconds
b2d02a400fe3: Retrying in 9 seconds
fc0e50be166d: Waiting
a8cfe888247e: Waiting
e745d991dded: Waiting
7b08edaa4533: Waiting
01b4d034aab5: Waiting
d0c686d0df68: Waiting
9deb78b26d56: Waiting
0566c118947e: Waiting
6f9cf951edf5: Waiting
182d2a55830d: Waiting
5a4c2c9a24fc: Preparing
cb11ba605400: Waiting
```

After about a minute or so of waiting, it finally prints the following error and terminates `received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error`

Obviously, this leaves me without some much-desired functionality. Would anyone be able to help me find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a permission error where docker didn't have the permission to write to the mounted directory (do a `chmod 777` to fix).

The `docker log` command was a trusty friend in helping me (well, my supervisor) trace the error to its source